# What determines the difficulty for capturing a tile?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

What determines the difficulty for capturing a tile in Bloons Monkey City?

I already know that strongest bloon, terrain type, theme (such as Regrow Rush of Death) and your level affect the difficulty, but I don't quite understand the determination in the difficulty of the pictures shown below. All of these pictures are when I was Level 19.
[image]

[image]
[image]

All of these tiles have a "normal" theme (i.e. no theme) and are jungle terrain. As you can see, the first picture has a max of lead but is the same difficulty as a MOAB, which is multiple times stronger than a lead, and a tile with max ceramic is somehow HARDER than a tile with a MOAB. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The difficulty of each piece of land relative to the player's level
>   and choice of buildings can be inferred from the number of dots,
>   ranging from one coloured in dot (trivial) to five coloured in dots
>   (very hard) or five dark colored dots (impoppable). Some tracks on
>   certain tiles are notably more difficult than others, and thus those
>   tiles will have a slightly higher difficulty rating than tiles near
>   it. Most tiles will restrict a player from using one or two towers,
>   such as water tiles, where one can not use Ninja Monkey towers or Bomb
>   Shooter towers (Excluding the special mission 'Shipwreck' or 'Sub
>   Alliance' in Mobile)

Source:
[Bloons Monkey City Wiki](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Bloons_Monkey_City)

It goes into more detail on that page, but it deals with the dots under the balloons and what color they are.

Comment: Well all three of them are Jungle terrains and so the same towers are restricted. Does that mean it is dependent on the SPECIFIC track?

Comment: You could say that.  The track, the special requirements for that land piece, all of that would be included on how difficult it is.  That's how they rate it with the dots.

Comment: The difficulty may also depend on how the bloons come out (for example, spaced ceramics vs grouped ceramics). I'm not so sure about that but it's just my theory.